# How can I get a subtotal for each t.title?

Tags: sql

I run this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.title,  t.role  
  FROM titles t, employees e
  WHERE e.employee_title=t.title
```

and my result is:

title   role
developer   researcher
tester  supervision
sales   support

But what I really want is include the number of each title and the total wages of that title. So I tried this
SELECT DISTINCT t.title,  t.role, COUNT(e.employee_title), SUM(w2_wages)
FROM titles t, employees e
WHERE e.employee_title=t.title

But this yields just this:

```
 title        role      Count    sum
developer   researcher  20      1057267
```

What I really want is this line for EACH title.

How do I modify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.title, t.role, COUNT(e.employee_title), SUM(w2_wages)
FROM titles t JOIN
     employees e 
     ON e.employee_title = t.title
GROUP BY t.title, t.role;
```